# more models merged to one event variable 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, merge

when during a bigger site, i wan't to make a dashboard, and on the dashborad i want some kind of "events" or "activity".. so i'd figured this out

```
# Controller
replies = current_user.replies.order('updated_at desc')
topics = current_user.topics.order('updated_at desc')

@events = (replies + topics)
```

```
# View
  - for event in @events
    %div.forum-row
      %div.date
        = link_to "Link", event  
        = time_ago_in_words(event.updated_at)
        =t :home_ago
      %div.by
        = t(:home_by, :href => link_to(event.user.username, "#")).html_safe

      %div.clear
        = "&nbsp;".html_safe

      %div.clear
```

And that's work fantastic, but i want to at first make a bold line where it says what type it is.. like

"**Posted a Topic**: You posted a **Topic** 4 minutes ago"

or something like that.. But i can't see how to do that when i'm merging them together in the on @events..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the object class name to output the type of event:

```
"Posted a #{event.class.name}: You posted a #{event.class.name} 4 minutes ago"
```